# Вывод поля с бд

Tags: php, вывод

Когда пользователь регистрируется на сайте и после регистрации ему показывает сообщение $info_reg = 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались! Ваша реферальная ссылка: 
какой ключ можно присвоить параметру id для дальнейшей идентификации реферера по данной ссылке
Также есть php файл referal.php с кодом

```
<?
$_SESSION['ref_id']=$_GET['id'];
header('Location: register.php');
?>
```

Comment: $info_reg = 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались! Ваша реферальная ссылка: <a href= "//localhost/site/referal.php?id=  какой код писать после id=

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста код файла register.php. Конкретно его не хватает для точного ответа на ваш вопрос